# Como criar uma pesquisa em PHP e MYSQL

Tags: php

Banco de dados: Cadastro

Tabela = Pessoas

Registros: id, nome,sexo e telefone

index.php

```
<form method="post" action="index2.php">
        <input type="text" name="pesquisar" placeholder="pesquisa"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
</form>
```

envia.php

```
<?php
     $servidor = "localhost";
     $usuario = "root";
     $senha = "";
     $dbase= "exemplo";

     $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbase);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo seu arquivo envia.php, suponho que você já saiba executar *queries* em PHP. Se não souber, você pode perguntar por aqui ou consultar a classe [`mysqli` do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (que é uma boa forma de se conectar com banco de dados MySQL).

Você pode usar a função [`LIKE` do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html). Um exemplo está abaixo.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE nome LIKE '%".$pesquisar."%'";
```

Suponha que o usuário digitou **ari** no campo HTML. O MySQL irá buscar por qualquer nome que tenha a substring **ari**. Assim, nomes como M**ari**a, L**ari**ssa, M**ari**ana, **Ari**ane, Saf**ari** aparecerão nos resultados.

---

Você pode talvez melhorar sua pesquisa, pesquisando primeiro pelos registros cujos campos possuem valor igual ao pesquisado, ou seja, só o que for exatamente igual ao que o usuário pesquisou; depois, o que começar com o que o usuário pesquisou; depois, o que terminar com o que o usuário pesquisou; e, por fim, o que conter o que o usuário pesquisou.

Uma forma de fazer

```
$pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisar'];
$column = "nome";

$querybase = "SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE ".$column." "; 
$query = $querybase." = '".$pesquisar."';";        // Os que são idênticos ao pesquisado
$query .= $querybase."LIKE '".$pesquisar."%';";   // Os que começam com o que o usuário pesquisou 
$query .= $querybase."LIKE '%".$pesquisar."';";   // Os que terminam com o que o usuário pesquisou 
$query .= $querybase."LIKE '%".$pesquisar."%' AND ".$column." NOT LIKE '".$pesquisar."%' AND ".$column." NOT LIKE '%".$pesquisar."';";  // Os que possuem o que o que o usuário pesquisou excluindo os que começam e os que terminam (já pesquisados).
```